# Getting a specific versioned row in HBase

Tags: hbase

I have an HBase table that has 2 versions.  How do I `get` the row of a specific version?

```
create 'mytable', {NAME=>'cf1',VERSIONS=>2}

put 'mytable', 'row1', 'cf1:lang','english', {VERSIONS=>1}  //version 1 value
put 'mytable', 'row1', 'cf1:lang', 'spanish', {VERSIONS=>2} //version 2 value

get 'mytable','row1'                               //gets the latest version
COLUMN                                   CELL                                                                                                                
 cf1:lang                                timestamp=1521884601517, value=spanish
```

Now I want to get the row that has the value `english`, so I do

```
get 'mytable','row1',{COLUMN=>'cf1',VERSIONS=>1}  //I expect 'english'
COLUMN                                   CELL                                                                                                                
 cf1:lang                                timestamp=1521884601517, value=spanish
```

probably I have misunderstood versions in HBase.  Any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

When create, `VERSIONS=>2` means that row remain 2 versions of data.
When get, `VERSIONS=>1` means that the most recent 1 data will return.

**Get a specific version, you can achieve that by using [explicit version](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/versions.html)**, which you can reference the following steps:

```
hbase(main):062:0> create 'mytable', {NAME=>'cf1',VERSIONS=>2}
0 row(s) in 1.2360 seconds

=> Hbase::Table - mytable
hbase(main):063:0> put 'mytable', 'row1', 'cf1:lang', 'english', 1521900360000
0 row(s) in 0.0160 seconds

hbase(main):064:0> put 'mytable', 'row1', 'cf1:lang', 'spanish', 1521900370000
0 row(s) in 0.0030 seconds

hbase(main):065:0> get 'mytable','row1',{COLUMN=>'cf1',TIMESTAMP => 1521900360000}
COLUMN                                        CELL
 cf1:lang                                     timestamp=1521900360000, value=english
1 row(s) in 0.0030 seconds
```

Comment: I was aware that timestamp was an option but it is impractical. Any other ways other than timestamp?

Comment: i don't think there is other way by now :( maybe coprocessor may help, but not sure.